# Convert numeric columns to factors with different labels using key

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, lapply, r-factor

I have a data set that has 900 columns of numeric data and I need to convert the numeric columns to factors that have labels. Many labels will repeat. I am trying to write a function that will take the numeric columns, identify the type of label that the column needs, and then apply that label.

Here is an example data frame:

```
#create data frame with columns a,b,c,d
a<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
b<-c(0,1,0,1,0)
c<-c(1,0,1,0,1)
d<-c(2,3,4,5,3)

x<-as.data.frame(cbind(a,b,c,d))
```

I have a separate dataframe (i.e. y) that includes a key (i.e. column e) that identifies which factor labels should be applied to which of the columns (i.e. column f). Notice that b and c should have the same label.

```
e<-c(1,2,2,3)
f<-c("a","b","c","d")

y<-as.data.frame(cbind(e,f))
```

I would like to write a function that does the following, but automated. Here are the example labels that I would like to apply to a,b,c,d--where a and d are different, but b and c are the same.

```
x$a<-factor(x$a,
    levels=c(1,2,3,4,5),
    labels=c("Less than 25%",
    "25-50%",
    "51-75%",
    "76-90%",
    "More than 90%"))

x$b<-factor(x$b,
    levels=c(0,1),
    labels=c("Yes","No"))

x$c<-factor(x$c,
    levels=c(0,1),
    labels=c("Yes","No"))

x$d<-factor(x$c,
    levels=c(1,2,3,4,5),
    labels=c("l","m","n","o","p"))
```

With the final data set looking like:

```
>x
              a   b   c d
1 Less than 25% Yes  No m
2        25-50%  No Yes n
3        51-75% Yes  No o
4        76-90%  No Yes p
5 More than 90% Yes  No n
```

In the actual data set, there will be close to 60 labels.

Comment: Do you have the information about what the levels and labels for each variable should be stored somewhere or are you using some logic that will tell you what the levels and labels should be?

Comment: I have the levels and labels, but they will need to be manually written.

Comment: If they are not yet stored anywhere, I'm not sure how you get around writing out the levels and labels unless there is some logic that can be used based on the actual dataset to guess what they should be.  In your example, however, I don't see what the logic could be, particularly for the labels.

Comment: @aosmith So, I'm not trying to automate the levels and labels. I am trying to automate the application of labels to the 900 columns based on 60 written labels that correspond to the key. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm asking because if you have the labels and levels associated written in a way that they can be matched with the `e` of your second dataset, this would be pretty easy via `purrr:pmap_df`.  But if those aren't readily available it is not a viable solution.

Comment: @aosmith I could do that. I am not worried about writing the labels and levels, but automatically applying them to all columns based on key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can get the labels and levels appropriately associated with the `e` column, which is your link to the columns of the dataset, you can do this via `purrr:pmap_df`.

Here's how that would look.  Most of the work is in getting the labels and levels as a list column, which I do via `tibble` (loaded with dplyr).

Starting with your second dataset, `y`, which is an important part of this.

```
e = c(1,2,2,3)
f =  names(x)

y = data.frame(e,f)

  e f
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 2 c
4 3 d
```

Make sure the levels and labels are available and can be associated with your `e` vector.  If they are in a long format, you could get them into a list-column format via `tidyr::nest`.  I found this to be the most time-consuming step in terms of getting this info written out.

```
library(dplyr)

levels.labels = tibble(e = c(1, 2, 3),
             levels = list(1:5, 0:1, 1:5),
             labels = list(c("Less than 25%",
                             "25-50%",
                             "51-75%",
                             "76-90%",
                             "More than 90%"),
                           c("Yes","No"),
                           c("l","m","n","o","p")))
```

If you needed to write your levels and labels out within R you might want to try `tribble`, which is available in the development version of the *tibble* package.

```
library(tibble)
levels.labels  = tribble(~e, ~levels, ~labels,
      1, 1:5, c("Less than 25%",
               "25-50%",
               "51-75%",
               "76-90%",
               "More than 90%"),
      2, 0:1, c("Yes","No"),
      3, 1:5, c("l","m","n","o","p"))
```

Merge the levels and labels with your `y` dataset based on `e`.  The rows of the result is a 1 to 1 match of the columns of `x`.

```
key = left_join(y, levels.labels)

  e f        levels                                               labels
1 1 a 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 Less than 25%, 25-50%, 51-75%, 76-90%, More than 90%
2 2 b          0, 1                                              Yes, No
3 2 c          0, 1                                              Yes, No
4 3 d 1, 2, 3, 4, 5                                        l, m, n, o, p
```

To factor each column, put the x dataset, the levels, and the labels all into a named list.  The names of each element correspond to the names of the arguments you need to use from `factor`.  This allows you to easily use `pmap_df` from *purrr* to `factor` each column of `x`, using the known levels and labels information.

```
library(purrr)
pmap_df(list(x = x, levels = key$levels, labels = key$labels), factor)

# A tibble: 5 x 4
              a      b      c      d
         <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>
1 Less than 25%    Yes     No      m
2        25-50%     No    Yes      n
3        51-75%    Yes     No      o
4        76-90%     No    Yes      p
5 More than 90%    Yes     No      n
```

In `pmap` functions, the elements within the list must be all the same size.  In this case, the first element has 4 columns and the second two are vectors with length 4.

Comment: Would there be a way to input the levels, labels, and keys in excel or something and then have them imported to R for the tibble portion of this? What would be the ideal input method, to avoid splitting up writing the level/label values? Seems like it would be much easier to do all these at once, maybe column by column, rather than writing the levels, then scrolling down to write the label, then back up again for the level, etc.

Comment: Having a spreadsheet or other document for storing your levels, labels, etc. seems reasonable.  The above was just an example of what the table would look like, not a recommendation for how to type them out as I don't know how they are currently stored.  Another possible option for data entry is to store them in a long format (e.g., one row for each level) and use `tidyr::nest` once you read them into R.

Comment: When I try this on my actual data set the final pmap_df is empty. The column names are there, but all data on the data.frame is missing. Wondering what went wrong. I *did* get a warning message when left merging: Joining, by = "e"
Warning message:
In left_join_impl(x, y, by$x, by$y, suffix$x, suffix$y) :
  joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot without an example.  Maybe your `e` aren't lined up correctly for merging so the wrong levels and labels are used for making the factor? Although that should lead to NA, not empty.  In your example above `e` is numeric, not a factor, so wouldn't have that warning.

Comment: Sure. I think it is because I am trying to input the labels and levels in a csv file in excel. I am writing them separated by commas, but they are not being recognized as the c("1","2", etc.) that you wrote. Any idea how to get them from excel input as comma separated lists within a single cell to R?

Comment: If you have commas between your levels (but no `c` or `(` or quotes) and read your dataset in with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`, you can make the columns into lists via `mutate` and `strplit`.  If your levels need to be numeric in your real dataset you'll need to make them numeric after `strsplit`.  Example code for dataset read in called "ll2": `ll2 %>% group_by(e) %>% mutate(labels = strsplit(labels, ","), levels = list(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(levels, ",")))))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121614/discussion-between-sam-and-aosmith).